# Registry keys to change personalization settings?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, themes

I am aware that settings related to **Themes** and **Personalization** can be found here:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes
```

I can't find the specific settings I am looking for, which are:

- Automatically pick an Accent Color from my background (Enabled by Default; I want to disable)
- Show accent color on the following surfaces: Start Menu/Taskbar/Action Center & Titles Bars (Both disabled by default; I want them both enabled)
- Transparency (On by default I think; I want it off)
- Color (ability to set a specific color, i.e. a certain shade of green)

With the exception of color, they are all checkboxes or toggles.

So basically, I'm looking for keys I can put in a REG file so if I logon to a machine I've never used before, I can get the system to this state, simply by running the REG file:

[image]

I do not have administrative rights of any kind.

Comment: I would use GPOs if I could. I don't have control over that. I'm in a domain with over 10,000 users in my OU and no support or sympathy from IT. I've created my own logon/logoff scripts to automate everything, and they upgraded some machines from Win7 to Win10 so I'm in the process of refining my scripts. With Win7, Themes were disabled so I didn't have to worry about that. I hate the default black, so I want to change it to green and enforce some other customization. Can you give me the HKLU instead of HKLM? No admin rights. (Thankfully, I can use regedit now, couldn't before).

Comment: If you don't have Administrator rights on the domain, then I cannot help,  I will withdraw my comments in that case.

Comment: @Ramhound Why would I need local (let alone domain) admin rights in order to untick some checkboxes that affect only my user account in an automated fashion? I don't follow. Sure, I would love to have domain admin rights but that won't happen. If I did, I would use GPOs and configure the system images in order to get my intended result anyways, not 10 or 15 .bat and .reg files

Comment: You don't but I know of no other solution except one that requires it

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Active Window Border

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent]
"AccentColorMenu"=dword:ffb16300
```

#### Active Window Title Bar

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM]
"AccentColor"=dword:ffb16300
```

#### Inactive Window Title Bar

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM]
"AccentColorInactive"=dword:ffb16300
```

#### Transparency effects

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize]
"EnableTransparency"=dword:00000001
```

#### Show accent color on the following surfaces

Start, taskbar, and action center

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize]
"ColorPrevalence"=dword:00000001
```

Title bars

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM]
"ColorPrevalence"=dword:00000001
```

### Default app mode

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize]
"AppsUseLightTheme"=dword:00000001
```

#### Start Menu Tile

*Haven't figured it out yet*

#### App Accent Color

*Haven't figured it out yet*

### Various Windows Explorer, and Taskbar settings

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
```

Comment: What is the format of the data expected by, e.g., `AccentColor`? It looks like 0xBBGGRR? Also `AccentColorInactive` actually works in Windows 10 1909, even though I had to add that entry manually.

Answer (score 1):

For the answer above (Drew Chapin) - I suppose that's what you looking for:

**Start Menu Tile**
and
**App Accent Color**

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SystemProtectedUserData\S-1-5-******\AnyoneRead\Colors

Comment: The question now is how to reliably determine what the **** is so it can be used in a script. However, I don't use the Windows 10 Start Menu nor do I use any apps in Windows 10, so this is low priority for me. But this information is correct as I've confirmed on my system.

Comment: If you know the user name `wmic useraccount where name="USER" get sid` will return the SID. Requires that an account exists. If the user name is variable but uses the currently logged in account, use %username% system variable. If you prefer to do it computer wide, it can be forced with Group Policy.

This post is informative to read the wmic output correctly as a variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663557/how-do-i-store-the-second-line-of-output-into-a-variable-in-batch

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that "Automatically pick an accent color from my background" option leads to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM\ColorizationColorBalance` getting a value `0xfffffff3` (i.e. it overrides an actual colorization color balance).

Answer (score 0):

In the Registry, "Automatically pick an Accent Color from my background" can be enabled/disabled by setting the following key to `0` or `1`:

```powershell
HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\AutoColorization
```

The Powershell command is:

```powershell
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop" -Name "AutoColorization" -Value 1
```

Comment: This didn't work for me on Win10 21H2.