# How to use themes in windows 7 safe mode?

Tags: windows-7, themes, safe-mode

If there is a way to enable themes/personalization in win7 safe mode please tell me, I use safe mode for my everyday use because for some reason normal mode doesn't work for me at all.

Comment: It might be better to ask about your problems in normal mode. Safe mode is intended for troubleshooting, not for work.

Comment: For that matter, why use an operating systems that has been unsupported for years, cannot run modern software, and has no security updates? Perhaps if you are into antique OS, but then you would have fixed the current issue.

Comment: @NoOne That doesn't solve my issue, what registry keys do i have to change to make it work? WindowBlinds doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a third-party software like WindowBlinds, which allows you to customize the appearance of your Windows desktop with various skins and themes. WindowBlinds works in safe mode, but you need to have administrative rights to install and run it.

Another way is to use the registry editor to change some settings related to themes and personalization. This method does not require administrative rights, but it is more complicated and risky, as you might damage your system if you make a mistake you can find some things on [this superuser page](https://superuser.com/questions/1245923/registry-keys-to-change-personalization-settings)

Comment: "Stardock WindowBlinds generally has had a bad reputation within the Windows modification community due to various parts of the software being poorly optimized." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WindowBlinds Will this 80 MB app even run on Win 7??

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It certainly used to. I used to run older versions on Window 7